# Multiple materials on a single mesh cause z-index / clipping issue

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using threejs and currently trying to add two materials to a mesh. First material has a colour and the second material has a canvas texture. To do this I add the two materials to an array and then set the mesh's material to be the array. This works fine apart from a glitchy shadow at the top of the mesh which looks like a  [z-index overlapping problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPx5T.png)

Simplified code of two materials being created, one uses a canvas texture as its map. Then the two materials are added to an array and then the mesh.

```
const canvasTexture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(
    ctx.canvas,
    THREE.UVMapping,
    THREE.LinearFilter,
    THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter,
    THREE.RGBAFormat,
    THREE.UnsignedByteType,
    maxAnisotropy

);

const baseMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: #ffff00
});

const designMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    map: canvasTexture,
    transparent: true
});

const materials = [baseMaterial, designMaterial];

myObject.material = materials;
```

So my question is, how do I set the z-index of the materials in the array so that i dont get the glitchy shadow? Or is there something else i can do to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out the answer myself.

Not sure why this code was present, but when my object is rotated in the scene then the lighting position is updated:

```
scene.lights.position.set(this.scene['camera'].position.x, this.scene['camera'].position.y, this.scene['camera'].position.z);
```

This caused a mesh behind the mesh i was editing to clip through. I still need to remove the mesh the was clipping through but for the meantime not changing the light position has solved the issue.

Hope this is able to help someone coming across similar problems.

Comment: Tip: use `.copy( position )` instead of `.set( position.x, position.y, position.z )`.

Comment: Thanks @WestLangley ill use that instead